# Parse String to Int Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin, numberformatexception

How to parse **String** to **Int**

get value from edittext

my Code:

```
var data = input.text.toString().trim().toInt()
    for (a in 0..data){
    }
```

but i have error

> NumberFormatException: For Input String " "

Comment: You are trying to convert space character into integer. That's why it doesn't work. Instead, you need to fix your input

Comment: i just insert a number.

Comment: Yes, but the error is showing that the value of `input.text.toString().trim()` at that execution is a space character `" "`

Comment: so just `var data:Int = input.text.toString().toInt()`, sorry i'm newbie in kotlin

Answer (score 2):

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4502035/andreas) mentioned in a comment, the value of input.text.toString().trim() is " ". This suggests the error is somewhere else in your code. But if you want to be able to handle these errors without throwing an exception you could use toIntOrNull() and do something like:

```
var data = input.text.toString().trim().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
for (a in 0..data){
    //...
}
```

This will ensure that data equals 0 in the event the string is not valid.

I'm not sure why the error you're getting is saying " " though, as trim() should have turned it into "". Are you sure you posted the error message verbatim?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but the value of `input.text.toString().trim()` not be a `Interger`
Make sure it correct and handle your case as below

```
var data: Int? = null
try {
      data = input.text.toString().trim().toInt()
} catch (ex: NumberFormatException) {
      // incorrect input
}
data?.let {
      for (a in 0..data) {
      // do something
      }
}
```